# Regular Expression: How to write nested search pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with writing RegEx pattern to find continuous sets of blocks like that:

pseudo code:

```
any sub-string consisted of any number of characters
finished with DDCC
repeated many times
```

For example I'd like to strings like this:
2342DDCC3423423DDCCfsfsfsfDDCC2weDDCC1312312qeqeDDCC
to be found.

The first part is easy: `[A-Za-z0-9]+DDCC`

However when I did: `[[A-Za-z0-9]+DDCC]+` function has returned an empty string.
How to code multiple repetition of the pattern, which internally has the repetition syntax itself?

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Comment: You should give several examples that fit or not your requirements to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+DDCC)(?1)+
```

`(?1)` means the same pattern as the first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

To capture all groups you can use following expression.

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+?DDCC)   // use global flag based on your language/tool
```

It will capture all groups ending at DDCC. The important thing to note here is the use of `?` after `[A-Za-z0-9]` which makes the matching non greedy.